# c# - Opening chosen file with associated App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have successfully prompted user to select a file in  C# using

the openFileDialog control.

I now have the filename, lets call it foo.docx

I want to open the file with the asssoicated app.

i.e., if it is a docx file, launch with word.

Is there a best way to just pass the filename and it do the launch ?

I used System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());

TIA.

Ralph

Comment: The `FileName` property of the `OpenFileDialog` already returns a string, so there's no need to call `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) with the file name - the OS will select the associated application.

```
Process.Start(@"path to\foo.exe");
```

Comment: This is what I used System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());

Comment: @Ralph - can you please _edit_ your question and add the code and any other information you think you should add to it? This information can get "lost" in a comment.

Comment: @Ralph - Can you also expand on what _exactly_ you mean by "best way"? Readable code? Speed? Something else?

Comment: @Ralph - As far as I know, this is the standard and best way to do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
Process.Start(filename);
```

This will open the program in the default program set in Windows.

Also, you can use the same to open a URL in the user's default browser.